# How to Create dynemic translation file translations/messages.fr.xlf ,translations/messages.en.xlf in symfony2

Tags: php, xml, symfony, file-io, symfony-1.4

**How to Create dynemic translation file  translations/messages.fr.xlf ,translations/messages.en.xlf in symfony2**

i want the following file to create language wise (en ,fr  )

file name : messages.en.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Action</source>
                <target>Action EN</target>
            </trans-unit> 
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>Add</source>
                <target>Add EN</target>
            </trans-unit> 
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

i want to get `<source>` and `<target>` value from database but how to implement this code in symfony2

Comment: [Doctrine Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should use the awesome [JMSTranslationBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle) which gives you a web interface and a command to populate all your translations files.

Furthermore, you can use the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)

So read the documentation I gave you and follow the tutorial to setup this bundle and use it.

Hope this helps :)